# How to make Bond work in a OS X Swift app?

Tags: swift, macos

I'm almost embarrassed to ask what must be a basic question, but I can't get Bond to work with Swift 4. To try out Bond, I created a basic one-view MacOS app in Xcode. I used Carthage to get the latest Bond framework (and the ReactiveKit and Differ frameworks). I added the Bond framework to the Embedded libraries for the app, and added an "import Bond" statement to the app's default ViewController. On the view I added a NSButton and an NSTextField and hooked them up in IB. Here's the ViewController code:

```
import Cocoa
import Bond

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var txt_1: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet var btn_1: NSButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        _ = btn_1.reactive.tap.observeNext {
            print("Button tapped")
        }

        _ = txt_1.reactive.text.observeNext {
            text in
            print(text!)
        }

    }
```

The btn.reactive.tap.observeNext line gets a compiler error: "Value of type 'Reactive' has no member 'tap'".

The txt_1.reactive.text.observeNext line gets a similar error: "Value of type 'Reactive' has no member 'text'"

Clearly I have missed something, but I don't know what. I'm a reasonably competent (though amateur) Swift developer and have used other frameworks so I know how to get them to work, but this has me baffled. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to install it via Cocoapods? I assume that it requires  macOS 10.9+ and Xcode 9+

Comment: I have not tried installing via CocoaPods.The Carthage installation seems to  worked fine, as the iOS Bond framework works as it should. Would a CocoaPods installation make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

*"Do you expect me to work?" "No, Mr. Bond, I expect you to die!"*

I've not really dealt with these frameworks much, but a quick web search landed me on the [github page for the Bond framework](https://github.com/ReactiveKit/Bond), and poking around in the sources there provides a couple of hints:

1. The statements you're having trouble with seem to have more to do with ReactiveKit (the layer on which Bond builds) than Bond itself. You probably need to `import ReactiveKit` to see the full interface at hand, not just `import Bond`.
2. The "signals" ReactiveKit exposes seem to map to features of the underlying Cocoa (Touch) class. In UIKit, `UITextField` has a `text` property, but its AppKit analogue `NSTextField` doesn't — instead it has `stringValue`. Similarly, one doesn't `tap` an `NSButton`, so you probably need to dig through the Bond or ReactiveKit sources or docs to find the corresponding signal.

Comment: Rickster - Thanks for your response. My response to your response:
1. I've imported ReactiveKit and receive the same errors. Tutorials on Bond all import the Bond framework only, so I think it's okay to leave out ReactiveKit.
2. Both the NSButton.reactive.tap action and NSTextField.reactive.tap are Bond-specific signals. I've taken them directly from tutorials on using Bond. Note that the error refers to Reactive not having these methods, so I know these are the correct ways to use Bond. They just don't work for me!

Comment: Could you link the tutorial you're looking at? The only Bond tutorials I've come across in quick web searches discuss using it *with UIKit for iOS*. Those use `tap` actions on `UIButton` and `text` actions on `UITextField`. But I don't see those actions in the Bond/ReactiveKit sources for **NS**Button and **NS**TextField in AppKit for macOS.

Comment: Interesting...you're right that the tutorials are all for iOS, but when Carthage builds the frameworks, it builds one for each of these: iOS, MacOS, WatchOS and TvOS. I can't find any tutorials that show using Bond for MacOS, but I also can't find anything that says it's only for iOS. More sleuthing required...

Comment: This link has AppKit sources for Bond; https://github.com/ReactiveKit/Bond/tree/master/Sources/Bond/AppKit. Clearly, I'm doing something wrong because I'm not getting a Bond framework that has functionality for these AppKit controls. But I've checked and re-checked that I'm embedding the MacOS frameworks for Bond, ReactiveKit and Differ.

Answer (score 0):

After copious (ab)use of Xcode's code completion, I fumbled my way towards the solution below. Not sure if it's strictly speaking correct and/or idiomatic, but it seems to work as intended. However, considering the lack of documentation and tutorials for Bond & AppKit bindings, wiring up a whole application might be daunting. Maybe the learning curve flattens out once the respective fields & methods for the most common UI elements are identified.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var labelField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pushBtn: NSButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        _ = textField.reactive.editingString.observeNext {
            text in
            print(text)
        }

        _ = pushBtn.reactive.controlEvent.observeNext {
            _ in
            print("Button clicked")
        }

        textField.reactive.editingString.bind(to: labelField.reactive.stringValue)
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

What if you wanted to react to end of editing instead? There doesn't appear to be a method that is symmetric to `editingString`. There is the `textDid...` family of methods but those return a signal (instead of DynamicSubject<>, which in turn returns a reference to the text field itself (not the string value). Again, I found working but not necessarily idiomatic solutions:

```
    _ = textField.reactive.textDidEndEditing.observeNext {
        (textField, _) in
        print(textField.stringValue)
    }

    textField.reactive.textDidEndEditing
        .map { $0.0.stringValue }
        .bind(to: labelField.reactive.stringValue)
```

Comment: sm3 - 
Thanks so much for your efforts and this example. I really appreciate your posting your code. I'm on vacation for a while, but will try to squeeze in some time to try it out. I'll post how it goes, but again, thanks for your work.